# Swift2: String to date, format it and back to string. Found nil

Tags: ios, string, swift, date, formatter

I have a date string: `Sun, 07 Feb 2016 21:16:21 +0000`

And need it in: `dd.MM.yyyy`

Following method throws `fatal error: nil`

```
if parsedElement == "date" {
    if currentArticle.date.isEmpty {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        let tempDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tempDate!)

        currentArticle.date = convertedDate

    }
}
```

Debug:

> str    String    "Sun, 07 Feb 2016 21:16:21 +0000"
>
> tempDate    NSDate?    2016-02-07 21:16:21 UTC    0xe41bc67eba500000​
>
> convertedDate    String    "07.02.2016"

Looks great, but the moment I release "`currentArticle.date = convertedDate`"​ it says `convertedDate​ = nil`

Ideas?

PS: `currentArticle.date == isEmpty`

**EDIT:** The if loop runs 5 times. 
If I give `currentArticle.date = str` (only the date string), this is what the debugger says:

`1. str String  "Sun, 07 Feb 2016 21:16:21 +0000"`

`2. str ""`

`3. str String  "Thu, 04 Feb 2016 21:18:34 +0000"`

`4. str ""`

`5. str String  "Thu, 04 Feb 2016 18:57:14 +0000"`

Comment: What do you mean by 'release "currentArticle.date = convertedDate"​'?

Comment: With release I mean "continue program execution".

Comment: convertedDate it is a string. What is the currentArticle.date property type String or NSDate ?

Comment: Ok, so you're talking about stopping it at that line with a breakpoint? And then continuing program execution? convertedDate is a local constant, as soon as you leave the `if currentArticle.date.isEmpty` block, convertedDate will no longer exist, that's expected.

Comment: Like posted in my edit, I tryed to run the method without the date formatter. There are 3 "parsedElement"s. 3 Date String.
The first time my method runs with the date formatter, it is fine. But the 2nd loop, the "if currentArticle.date.isEmpty" != isEmpty. I don't get, why this causes an exception.
Shouldnt the loop skip this round and continue with the 3rd round where currentArticle.date is empty again?

Comment: What is the error it throws? Also, why do you have to put a date in in string format? Where are you getting the initial string for the date?

Comment: I'm getting confused with your edits and comments. You say 5 loops, but 3 parsed elements? Where is the error thrown, and as Fogmeister asks what is the error?

Comment: It looks like you're getting the date from some parsed JSON. Is that correct? If so that particular element of the JSON should just be an NSDate object. Not just a string.

Comment: Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value -> tempDate


The string is downloaded from a blog with XMLParser.


I need it as string to put it into a label.

Comment: The string: `let str = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value -> tempDate

I assume you're getting this error in the line:

```
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tempDate!)
```

This is because you're force unwrapping an  optional which is equal to nil. You should use optional binding to unwrap it, i.e.:

```
if let tempDate = tempDate {
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tempDate)
    currentArticle.date = convertedDate
}
```

Now the question of why your date formatter is not returning a value for `str` in this instance is all to do with your data. You can add an `else` to the above optional binding code block to display `str` in this instance to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.
And of course thank you for not just showing me the code, but explaining it to me. I'm sure I got it. Thank you very much.